# Extracting the coefficient of $x^n$ from a fraction

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I need help extracting the coefficient of $x^n$ from a $\frac{1-x}{1-2x}$.

So far I have that

\begin{align}
\frac{1-x}{1-2x} &= \frac{1}{1-2x} - x\frac{1}{1-2x}\\
&= \sum\limits_{k=0}(2x)^k - x\sum\limits_{k=0}(2x)^k
\end{align}

would it then be correct to say that

\begin{align}
[x^n]\frac{1-x}{1-2x} = 2^n - 2^{n-1}?
\end{align}

Comment: This looks correct (and nice) to me.

Comment: It surely has advantages to know that $2-1=1$ right? (;

Comment: Haha, yes :) thank you.

Comment: Another way: try polynomial division first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed.

Why ? For the two series you consider are of positive radius, hence you can identify the coefficients, as in any equality between integer series of **positive** radius.

And for your 'correct' answer, it's the same : $2^n - 2^{n-1} = 2^{n-1}(2-1)$... so, that's it.

Comment: Oh, indeed. Thank you.